# Csv to csv (XSLT)

Tags: excel, csv

We have to perform a CSV transformation into another CSV (1 file to 1 file). We are looking for a cheap solution. The first idea that popped into my mind was Excel, but the file will be to big.

1) Is it possible to do a CSV to CSV conversion through XSLT? I can't seem to find a tool or google result which tells me how I could possibly do it.

2) Is there a better approach to do CSV transformations?

Edit:
It should be possible to automate/schedule the process

Comment: All I found so far was the following: https://code.google.com/p/csvfix/

Comment: Here's an old, OLD data mapper community edition that would allow you to model your source and target CSV and map them.  It looks like it hasn't been modified in quite awhile: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jitterbit/files/

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is *far* too broad. Excel itself can analyze *millions* of rows, especially when you use Power Query - in fact you can perform all transformations there. For statistics, the only limit is available memory.  For saving, the 1M rows limit applies up to 2013. If you wanted to process a lot of files, you could use SQL Server Integration Services. Or you can write your own program in almost *any* language.

Comment: How big is this big file? How many rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answers below

1) No, XSLT only transforms XML files.

2) Yes, as the answer to question 1 is "No", it is reasonable to assert there are better approaches. As CSV is not a standardised format there are a plethora of varied approaches to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Rscript` to automate the transformation of CSV:

```
# Rscript --vanilla myscript.R
```

Where `myscript.R` is something like:

```
csv <- read.csv(file="input.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
# Modify your CSV ...
write.csv(data, file = "output.csv")
```